# PHP setcookie() expire issue on Vista

Tags: php, windows-vista

On one specific system configuration only (Win Vista, all browsers - all of them allow cookies) I discovered a problem with PHP setcookie. I have created two simple scripts to simplify problem identification:

**script_1.php** to set cookie

```
setcookie("name", "value", time()+3600);    
header("Location: script_2.php");
exit();
```

**script_2.php** to check result

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

With above syntax and mentioned config, no cookie "name" is created. When I remove "expire" parameter and leave just

```
setcookie("name", "value");
```

cookie "name" is set properly.

In Win XP, Win 7, Mac OSX 10.6, Androids, iPad, iPhone + any specific system compatible browsers everything works great with full cookie definition like

```
setcookie("name", "value", time()+3600, "/", "domain.com", 0, 1);
```

Just Vista has problems on any browser. Time setting on the server is OK.

Thanks for any advice, tip or solution. I am really stacked and helpless here.

Comment: But what about the date & time & timezone setting on the Vista machine?  If it's set far in the future, the cookie expiring in 1 hour will be expired immediately.

Comment: If _all_ browsers suddenly have an issue there (and cookies work, or Vista would be even more trashed then now), it makes me believe there is a firewall or proxy at work, or your computer time is way of (remember to check your timezone)... Well, firebug / chrome dev tools / fiddler for msie can at least tell you whether the cookie headers arrive at that location.

Comment: Can you reproduce this error on a second, unrelated Vista machine?

Comment: To Wrikken - maybe I am wrong, but would simle cookie setting work (I mean just with name and value parameters), if there either firewall or proxy blocks them?

Comment: To phihag - no, I have Win 7 machine, Vista machine, MacBook Pro, WinXP virtual machine on MacBook Pro, iPad, iPhone, Android phone for testing. On every system I have all available browsers installed. But I have no machine doubled, particularly if it should be another Win crap .o) but if you run Vista, I can send you the link to testing script_1.php, what result you achieve. Thanks a lot for all your comments, folks.

Comment: Big sorry to all who wasted their time with this question. I am lol. I installed Vista one day before putting the question here. I checked several times timezone, clock setting on local machine and just now found the stupid issue - newly installed system lives one day in the future. Sorry guys. Best regards